# How to change PAGESIZE in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, paging

I want to change `PAGE_SIZE` from `4096` for the experiment. So I changed the value of `PAGE_SHIFT` in `/arch/x86/include/asm/page_types.h`. But I can't compile it.

```
In file included from include/linux/linkage.h:4:0,
from include/linux/kernel.h:6,
from include/linux/cache.h:4,
from include/linux/time.h:4,
from arch/x86/kernel/vsyscall_64.c:23:
arch/x86/kernel/vsyscall_64.c: function ‘map_vsyscall’ 内:
include/linux/compiler.h:437:20: eroor: call to ‘compiletime_assert_390’ declared with attribute error: BUILD_BUG_ON failed: (unsigned long)__fix_to_virt(VVAR_PAGE) != (unsigned long)VVAR_ADDRESS
prefix ## suffix(); \
^
include/linux/compiler.h:442:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘__compiletime_assert’
__compiletime_assert(condition, msg, prefix, suffix)
^
include/linux/compiler.h:454:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘_compiletime_assert’
_compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __LINE)
^
include/linux/bug.h:53:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘compiletime_assert’
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG(cond, msg) compiletime_assert(!(cond), msg)
^
include/linux/bug.h:77:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG’
BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG(condition, "BUILD_BUG_ON failed: " #condition)
^
arch/x86/kernel/vsyscall_64.c:389:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘BUILD_BUG_ON ’
BUILD_BUG_ON((unsigned long)__fix_to_virt(VVAR_PAGE) !=
^
make[2]: * [arch/x86/kernel/vsyscall_64.o] eroor 1
make[1]: * [arch/x86/kernel] error 2
make: *** [arch/x86] error 2
```

Probably due to VVAR_PAGE, but I don't know how to change it.
What should i do?

Comment: It's not only software abstraction, but also MMU hardware configuration. If your architecture doesn't support that, you may not do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly modify the `PAGE_SIZE` by setting `PAGE_SHIFT` as it is generated at compile-time.

Assuming your processor is a x86, you can modify your page size up to 8k with the family of variables `CONFIG_PAGE_SIZE_XXX` such as `CONFIG_PAGE_SIZE_8KB`. Note that using big pages will take *a lot* of space unnecessarily as even 1-byte files takes a full page on disk. Also, changing the page size is architecture dependant and it is recommended to keep the default 4K size.

A better approach though, might be to use huge pages, more flexible and more powerful. [They are presented there](https://lwn.net/Articles/374424/)

Comment: Thank you. However i can not find it. Where is `CONFIG_PAGE_SIZE_XXX`?